# Use Android Native code as Android Titanium Module

Tags: android, module, titanium, appcelerator, native

I have a native Android Java code that compiles and works perfectly. I also have a Appcelerator Alloy code that I need to call some Activity of that native app and wait for a response event.
I've already read the Development Guide ([available here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Quick+Start)) but since I have to create a structure using TiViewProxy I got stuck.

How could I create an Android Module for Titanium to use that APK code as a "black box"?

Comment: Do you want to build a custom app with your java code and communicate with that (last sentence) or do you want to create a module and integrate your java code into your Titanium app (the part about the dev.guide)? For the first option you need to look at intents, for the other one you can either create a module and use your code in the app or even use hyperloop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @miga . That's the question: "... you can create a module and use your code in the app or even use hyperloop". The code structure for the Titanium Android Modules uses things like TiViewProxy that is not present on original Android code. I don't know if it helps to clear my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the next guide at: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Android+Module+Architecture
it will explain what a TiViewProxy is and how to use it.

But if you module is not using a special GUI you don't need it. If you create a new module with `appc new` and select `Titanium module` you'll get a default project. Open the `NameModule.java` file add your Android code and use/extend the example properties/methods inside that file to communicate between your module and your Titanium App.

Also have a look at some other open source modules e.g. https://github.com/appcelerator-modules on how to implement stuff.

And if you want to skip the module part have a look at Hyperloop:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Hyperloop
and some examples: https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples

Perhaps your JAVA part can be added to Titanium right away